# Running a loop multiple times automatically with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have succeeded in cobbling together pieces of code that achieve my goal. However, I would like some advice from more advanced vanilla JS programmers on how I can go about reaching my goal in a better way.

To start, I want to introduce my problem. I have a piece of text on my website where a portion is designed to change every so often. For this, I am running through a loop of phrases. To run this loop continuously, I first call the loop, then I call it again with setInterval timed to start when the initial loop ends. Here is the code I've got, which works even if it isn't what could be considered quality code:

```
function loop(){

for (let i = 0; i < header_phrases.length; i++){
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          header_txt.textContent =  header_phrases[i];
        }, 3000 * i);
    })(i);
};
}

loop();
setInterval(loop, 21000);
```

Is there a better way to right this code for both performance and quality? Do I need to use async? If so, any material I can see to learn more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the same logic using recursion.

```
function recursify(phrases, index = 0) {
    header_txt.textContent = phrases[index];
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursify(phrases, index < phrases.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0);
    }, 300)
}

recursify(header_phrases);
```

The function 'recursify' will call itself after 300 miliseconds, but everytime this function gets called, the value of index will be different.

Comment: It isn't recursion if the function is called from `setTimeout`.  It is always at the top of the call stack.

Comment: @Amy what do you mean exactly? Ok, the function doesn't call itself directly, but the process invoked is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want top populate an element from an array of values.

A simple way to do this is:

```
doLoop();
function doLoop() {
    var phraseNo=0;
    setTimeout(next,21000);
    next();
    function next() {
        header_txt.textContent =  header_phrases[phraseNo++];
        if(phraseNo>=header_phrases.length) phraseNo=0;
    }
}
```

This simply puts the `next()` function on the queue and waits.

The call to `next()` before the function simply starts it off without waiting for the timeout.

Comment: That's merely two calls, not a loop.

Answer (score 0):

this is assuming that `header_txt` and `header_phrases` are not global vars. using global vars isn't a good idea.

```
var repeatIn = 3000;
phraseUpdater();

function phraseUpdater() {
    var updateCount = 0,
        phrasesCount = header_phrases.length;

    setHeader();
    setTimeout(setHeader, repeatIn);
    function setHeader() {
        header_txt.textContent = header_phrases[updateCount++ % phrasesCount] || '';
    }
}
```